# How to change background color in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I have a switcher that changes the theme of the websitesite to light and dark. Now it uses default colors: black and white. How to change these colors to my custom?
Code provided in [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/jovial-http-wt5voc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Trying to change colors in palette attribute, it doesnt helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in the [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/dark-mode/#dark-mode-with-a-custom-palette) the instructions to customize the palette according to the selected mode.

Here is a possible solution based on the light `#b42b2b` and dark `#222` colors present in your example :

```
const theme = React.useMemo(
  () => {
    const customProps = (mode === "light") ? {
      background: {
        default: "#b42b2b",
        paper: "#b42b2b"
      }
    } : {
      background: {
        default: "#222",
        paper: "#222"
      }
    };

    return createTheme({
      palette: {
        mode,
        ...customProps
      }
    });
  },
  [mode]
);
```

I only customized `background` but you can customize much more properties. Here the [list of properties](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/default-theme/) present in the default theme.
You can see their default values in light and dark mode, so you can decide which ones you want to customize.

If you want to add [custom color](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#providing-the-colors-directly), you must provide all these properties `light`, `main`, `dark` and `contrastText`.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    custom: {
      light: '#ffa726',
      main: '#f57c00',
      dark: '#ef6c00',
      contrastText: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)',
    }
  }
});
```

and use the custom color like this :

```
<Button color="custom">
```

```
const Div = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.custom.main
}));
```